# How to count the selected and un selected dropdowns in jquery?

Tags: jquery

```js
$('.AttributeList option:selected[value="null"]').length
```

I have 4 ddl. the first option is "Select". I have tried this. If te option is select then i need to count how many ddl have selected value.

Comment: what is value of "Select" in your dropdowns?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code is working for me.

```
 $('.AttributeList').each(function () {
                if ($.trim($(this).val()).length > 0)
                    levelcount++;
            });
```